# Catagories to the list of the titles in that catagory to the content of the post

Tags: theme-development, design

[image]

Wordpress homepage is shown. On the left sidebar catagories are shown. When the user clicks the category the post title related to that clicked category is populated on the middle part. Now when the user clicks the title in the second step, the content is shown in the third step. All the title of the post from that catogery should still be shown in the step 2.

What I have done so far?

I have done till 2 step. Now but when the title is clicked in the 2 step, the list of the post vanishes and only the title is shown.

```
<div  class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div  class="col-3">
        <?php get_sidebar();?>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-3">
        <?php 
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post(); ?>
                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php } 
            } wp_reset_postdata();?>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-6">
       //No idea how to show the content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of the post is called by `<?php the_content; ?>`
https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action

Comment: I know that. But if you click the link in step 2,  the list of the posts of the category selected in step 1 will be replaced with only the post title of the clicked post. Even though the content is shown, i still want the list of posts of that catagory to be shown in step 2.